# How can I create an animation within a cloth simulation?

Tags: animation

I have been trying to create an animation (in which an avatar moves her arms) and I want it to run while a cloth simulation is happenning. I have tried this, but the cloth disappears in the simulation because of the animation, which is running at the same time. How can I make this work?

Comment: I have just solved this.

Comment: If you have solved this then please answer using the answer box below.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it: I created the skeletal animation as if there was no cloth simulation happening at the same time. After that, I created the cloth simulation and applied the collision modifier to the avatar. After baking the cloth simulation, I played the animation and it worked: the cloth responded to the skeletal animation and did not disappear.